# Dead Code Warning with Physicaloid Library

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am trying to build the project Android-USB-Serial-Monitor-Lite by using the source code from here https://github.com/ksksue/Android-USB-Serial-Monitor-Lite.

Added the physicoloid library as mentioned here 
https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary

But,I am getting Warnings(9) as Dead code as shown in the attached image.Every Warnign is related to the BuildConfig.DEBUG.

Can someone help me fixing this Dead Code warning.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's left for debugging purpose by developer.

Because it's false AND BuildConfig.DEBUG, it's always false regardless of latter and thus shows dead code warning.

You can see it determines whether to log or not.
So if you change to true and run debug, you can get logs.